# Laravel Guzzle call external API in event listener not retrieving data

Tags: laravel, events, guzzle

I have a problem where I am trying to use Laravel Guzzle to get response from external API but somehow I checked in log file the data does not retireved but only return empty array. Otherwise in postman I tried the same thing and get the expected response and data

below the response from :

> postman:

[image]

> laravel.log

[image]

Below is my code for the guzzle

```
 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $client = app('GuzzleClient')([
            'base_uri'  => env('API', 'http://000.000.0.00'),
            'timeout'   => 60,
            'verify'    => false,
        ]);
        $response = $client->get($url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => "Bearer "  . env('AUTH_API', "(dummy bearer)")
            ]
        ]);

        $result = $response->getBody();

        return $result;
```

Any help or hint will be appreciate . Thankyou :)

Comment: `getBody` returns the body object, to get the actual contents as a string you'd do `getBody()->getContents()`

Comment: @apokryfos , the contents show empty .

Comment: To clarify the issue is not that the response is empty but the `data` part of the response is empty?

Comment: @apokryfos basically yeah, not the response is empty but the data part from the response is empty if i log the response. But different if i test the API call using postman ,it return a correct response with data.

Comment: Try doing `dd($response->getContents())` to double check that the data is actually empty and it's not just an issue with the logging

Comment: You should give it a try to the Http Laravel Client instead of native Guzzle. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client();    
$response = $client->get($url, [
   'headers' => [
       'Accept' => 'application/json',
       'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
       'Authorization' => "Bearer "  . env('AUTH_API', "(dummy bearer)")
    ]
 ]);
 $result = json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);

 return $result;
```

Comment: Still the same. data property does not have return any value